# ffmpeg: make a video with multiple input files and formats

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make a video with multiple input files. 
I have a bunch of PNG files and mp4 files and I want to create a video for the duration of my audio file `body.mp3`

The video should be made using multiple inputs.

1. file `000000.PNG` for duration 17.56
2. file `01.mp4` (duration ~4.0)
3. file `100074.PNG` for duration 6.12
4. file `02.mp4` (duration ~4.0)
5. file `200074.PNG` for duration 7.84
6. file `03.mp4` (duration ~4.0)
7. file `300074.PNG` for duration 11.88

The total video will have only one audio from `body.mp3`. Assuming `body.mp3` duration is equal to all the inputs duration combined (+/- 2.0)

Could you please show me how to achieve this?

Edit: Same resolution for all the input files and same frame rate in all the `*.mp4` files. Some times, I may have `04.mp4` and `400074.PNG` also.

Comment: Same resolution in all inputs? Same framerate in all MP4s?

Comment: @Gyan Yeah... same resolution for all the inputs and framerate in all the MP4s. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the framerate of the MP4s is 30, then you would use

```
ffmpeg -i body.mp3
       -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 17.56 -i 000000.PNG
       -i 01.mp4
       -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 6.12  -i 100074.PNG
       -i 02.mp4
       -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 7.84  -i 200074.PNG
       -i 03.mp4
       -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 11.88 -i 300074.PNG
-filter_complex "[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0[v]"
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

(All in one line; use single-quotes if you're on linux/OSX)

Comment: you are a life saver.. thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please explain what the -filter_complex and -map does? 

I'm trying to add more inputs(1-8 .mp4 and PNGs) to the above script and it won't encode the newly added inputs.